# can't take screenshots with pyscreenshot python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to follow a tutorial and this is the code:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import os,time

def screenGrab():
    box = ()
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +'.png','PNG')
    im.show()

def main():
    screenGrab()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run the code but no screenshot shows or is saved. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is important in python.

Comment: No error message ?

Comment: no there is no error message